# Using object as property of another object

Tags: javascript

I want to use an object template as a property of another object. My template object is like below

```
var tableDataRow ={
    numberOfFiles:parseFloat(0),
    insurerIncurred :parseFloat(0),
    insuredIncurred :parseFloat(0),
    totalIncurred :parseFloat(0)
};
```

I'm using this object like this

```
var tableData ={
    firm1 :tableDataRow,
    firm2:tableDataRow,
    firm3:tableDataRow,
    firm4:tableDataRow
};
```

But when I want to change a property value in `tableDataRow` object, all values in `tableData` are changing.

```
tableData.firm1.numberOfFiles = 2;
tableData.firm2.insurerIncurred = 3;
tableData.firm3.insuredIncurred = 4;
tableData.firm4.totalIncurred = 5;
```

I thought that I can use like object oriented languages but I supposed that this way I have only put a reference of `tableDataRow` in another object. How can I do this ?

https://jsfiddle.net/0ta0wkho/

Comment: Objects in Javascript are passed by reference, check Object.assign

Comment: Yes, this is correct behaviour - you might want to clone it then use the clone if you want the original to stay as a template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects are passed by reference, since the structure of yours is simple enough, you could get away with doing something like this `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(tableDataRow))` which would create a new object with the same structure as your original one, or you could have a function that returns that structure; if that makes it cleaner for you.

Here's a [fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xmymm71e/1/), if it makes it clearer

By having a function:

```
function cloneme(originalObject) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObject));
}
```

And assigning like this:

```
var tableData = {
  firm1: cloneme(tableDataRow),
  firm2: cloneme(tableDataRow),
  firm3: cloneme(tableDataRow),
  firm4: cloneme(tableDataRow)
};
```

We are working with new copies of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here all the fields are referring to the same object 
You may assign a clone of the object to fields of the `tableData` object.

Corrected code

```js
var tableDataRow = {
  numberOfFiles: parseFloat(0),
  insurerIncurred: parseFloat(0),
  insuredIncurred: parseFloat(0),
  totalIncurred: parseFloat(0)
};

var tableData = {
  firm1: Object.assign({}, tableDataRow),
  firm2: Object.assign({}, tableDataRow),
  firm3: Object.assign({}, tableDataRow),
  firm4: Object.assign({}, tableDataRow),
};

tableData.firm1.numberOfFiles = 2;
tableData.firm2.insurerIncurred = 3;
tableData.firm3.insuredIncurred = 4;
tableData.firm4.totalIncurred = 5;

console.log(tableData);
```

You can otherwise write a constructor for `TableDataRow` and assign instances of it to all the fields

Here is one of the ways of doing it

```js
function TableDataRow() {
  this.numberOfFiles = parseFloat(0),
    this.insurerIncurred = parseFloat(0),
    this.insuredIncurred = parseFloat(0),
    this.totalIncurred = parseFloat(0)
};

var tableData = {
  firm1: new TableDataRow(),
  firm2: new TableDataRow(),
  firm3: new TableDataRow(),
  firm4: new TableDataRow()
};

tableData.firm1.numberOfFiles = 2;
tableData.firm2.insurerIncurred = 3;
tableData.firm3.insuredIncurred = 4;
tableData.firm4.totalIncurred = 5;

console.log(tableData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `tableDataRow` as a function returning your template object. This way, you can use its individual instance while assigning it to `tableData.firm1` and so on.

```js
var tableDataRow = function(){
    return {
      numberOfFiles:parseFloat(0),
      insurerIncurred :parseFloat(0),
      insuredIncurred :parseFloat(0),
      totalIncurred :parseFloat(0)
    }
};
var tableData ={
    firm1: new tableDataRow,
    firm2: new tableDataRow,
    firm3: new tableDataRow,
    firm4: new tableDataRow
};

tableData.firm1.numberOfFiles = 2;
tableData.firm2.insurerIncurred = 3;
tableData.firm3.insuredIncurred = 4;
tableData.firm4.totalIncurred = 5;

console.log(tableData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clone the object first because  javascript passes object be reference. Try this code:

```
function clone(obj) {
if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
var copy = obj.constructor();
for (var attr in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
}
return copy;
}
var tableDataRow ={
numberOfFiles:parseFloat(0),
insurerIncurred :parseFloat(0),
insuredIncurred :parseFloat(0),
totalIncurred :parseFloat(0)
};

var tableData ={
firm1 :clone(tableDataRow),
firm2:clone(tableDataRow),
firm3:clone(tableDataRow),
firm4:clone(tableDataRow)
};

tableData.firm1.numberOfFiles = 2;
tableData.firm2.insurerIncurred = 3;
tableData.firm3.insuredIncurred = 4;
tableData.firm4.totalIncurred = 5;

console.log(tableData);
```